# Can I make a version of windows that resets everytime I boot it?

Tags: windows-10, boot, portable

I want to install Windows on a hard drive (I don't know if a USB would work) so it works like this:

- boot Windows, use it, turn off the computer.
- when I turn it back on, all I did before is erased, and its fresh, boots in a state where I planned (with some software that I installed and such), and every time, that same state, suffers no changes.

Kind of a read-only state, but I need to work with files, so not actually read-only.

Comment: See this article [create Windows to go](https://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/).

Comment: @Biswa this keeps all changes, WinToGo is like a normal Windows. He wants [Kiosk mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[deep freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze/)** software offer above feature.

**How to use:**

1. Get ready your system in final stage (you want to freeze)
2. Install this software (you can choose only windows or entire hard drive)
3. That's it!!!

Now, whatever you do will be removed on next restart. And if you want to modify or want to keep something permanent then you can disable it and re-enable after installation.

**NOTE:** It is PAID but they offer 30 days trial so you can test it.

Comment: thanks, is there a feature where i choose a folder for example, and that folder keeps the changes that happen to it ?

Comment: nope, you can choose between partitions only. Which means, you can set it to freeze only Windows Partition (C Drive) And place your other content in other drives (D, E etc)

Comment: You are welcome and don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a built-in feature called the [Unified Write Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unified-write-filter) which does exactly as you describe. The boot volume is read-only. Any changes you make are redirected to RAM or another storage device and are discarded when you reboot the machine. You can even use it to protect a single folder if you want.

Sadly, this feature is only available on the Enterprise and Education editions, not in the Home and Pro retail versions. However, it's pretty easy to qualify for the Education edition.